# C#: Change WindowState of main window from a different class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one the most default class of my window and second class I call from it. I need to change the `WindowState` of a `MainWindow` window from that second class but when I try to do it by: `MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;` it gives me this error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, of property 'Window.WindowState'`.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
namespace Client_Patcher
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**UnminimizeApplicationCommand.cs**:

```
namespace Client_Patcher
{
    public class UnminimizeApplicationCommand : ICommand
    {
        public UnminimizeApplicationCommand(WindowState d)
        {
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //Need to change WindowState property of a MainWindow here.
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            remove
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I tried to do this:

```
namespace Client_Patcher
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow AppWindow { get; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppWindow = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called by `MainWindow.AppWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;` way, but gives the same error. What is the work aroud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you are treating `MainWindow` like a static object. But in fact it isn't. With this in mind and now when reading the error message again, you will realize that it informs you exactly about this issue. To solve this try

`Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;`

inside your *Execute* callback

Answer (score -2):

I recommend using something called an "IoC container"

Create a static class.

```
 public static IoC
 {
     private static Window _window;
     // The main window instance for your app
     public static Window Window => _window;

     // Here you pass your application's "main" window instance.
     // So all window related intractability happens only from this clas
     public static InitializeDI(Window window)
     {

         _window = window;


}

}
```

**Note:** 
You should really call this method in the `Main()` method where your application starts

Comment: Dependency injection doesn't make any sense here. That's bad at this point. The framework already exposes a static property to access the main window. And if not, you rather would set a custom static property the very moment you initialize the main window, typically from App.xaml.cs.